# Post request status 500

Tags: python-requests

I want to upload a jpg file to a server using python post request. I used a curl command that works fine:

```
curl --cacert C:\cacert.pem -u user:key -F "data=@picture.jpg" https://serverurl/users/pictures
```

I am using the following python request but it gives me a status 500 response.

```
picture = {'data' : ('picture',open('picture.jpg','rb'))}
req = requests.post(
    'https://serverurl/users/pictures',
    files=picture, auth=('user','key'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your curl command is POSTing a form with "data=@picture.jpg" while you are uploading a local file using requests. [Have you read the doc](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)?

Try something different:

```py
session = requests.Session()
session.post('https://serverurl/users/pictures',
    data={'data': 'picture.jpg'}, cert='C:\cacert.pem', auth=('user':'pass'))
```